# Contents of div (a table) doesn't transition properly

Tags: css, vb.net, html, html-table, transition

I have a table within a div, and the div is a modal box. I'm trying to get it to fade in (as in, make visible slowly either through visibility or opacity option), however I can get the background of the div to transition, but the contents and table appear immediately (instead of fading in).  Can anyone please help me as this is driving me nuts!  Thanks.

```
<div id="ModalDiv" runat="server" class="ModalStartupClose">
    <table id="customers" runat="server" class="customers">
  <tr>
    <th>Company</th>
    <th>Contact</th>
    <th>Country</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Alfreds Futterkiste</td>
    <td>Maria Anders</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Berglunds snabbköp</td>
    <td>Christina Berglund</td>
    <td>Sweden</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Centro comercial Moctezuma</td>
    <td>Francisco Chang</td>
    <td>Mexico</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Ernst Handel</td>
    <td>Roland Mendel</td>
    <td>Austria</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Island Trading</td>
    <td>Helen Bennett</td>
    <td>UK</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Königlich Essen</td>
    <td>Philip Cramer</td>
    <td>Germany</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

The css details:

```
.customers {
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.customers td, .customers th {
    border: 2px solid #ddd;
    padding: 8px;
    opacity: 0;
    color: red;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.customersOpen {
    font-family: "Trebuchet MS", Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 100%;
    opacity: 1;
    color: blue;
    visibility: visible;
    transition: opacity 3s 2s, color 3s 2s, visibility 3s 2s;
}

    .customersOpen td, .customersOpen th {
        border: 2px solid #ddd;
        padding: 8px;
        opacity: 1;
        color: blue;
        visibility: visible;
        transition: opacity 3s 2s, color 3s 2s, visibility 3s 2s;
    }

    .customersOpen tr:nth-child(even) {
        background-color: #f2f2f2;
    }

    .customersOpen tr:hover {
        background-color: #ddd;
        transition: background-color 2s;
    }

    .customersOpen th {
        padding-top: 12px;
        padding-bottom: 12px;
        text-align: left;
        background-color: #4CAF50;
        color: white;
    }
```

And the code which is just contained within a button using vb.net:

```
customers.Attributes("class") = "customersOpen"
```